Interior of set of convergence is a Reinhardt domain
Let $S(z) = \sum_{\nu \ge 0} a_\nu z^\nu$ be a formal power series about the origin and
$$B:=\{z \in \mathbb{C}^n : S(z) \text{ is convergent}\}.$$
Abel's Lemma.
Let $P' \Subset P \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be polydisks around origin. If the power series $\sum_{\nu \ge 0} a_\nu z^\nu$ converges at some oint of the distinguished boundary of $P$, then it converges normally on $P'$.
Corollary. Let $P \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a polydisk around origin and $w$ be a point of the distinguished boundary of $P$. If the power series $\sum_{\nu \ge 0} a_\nu z^\nu$ converges at $w$, then it converges compactly on $P$.
Proposition. The interior $B^\circ$ is a complete Reinhardt domain, and $S(z)$ converges compactly in $B^\circ$.
Let's consider the projection map $\tau:\mathbb{C}^n \to (\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0})^n, \tau(z_1, \ldots, z_n) := (|z_1|, \ldots, |z_n|)$. Then, we denote by $T_z$ the torus $T_z:=\tau^{-1}(\tau(z))$ and by $P_z$ the polydisk $P_z := P^n(0, \tau(z))$ centered in $0$ and of polyradius $\tau(z)$.
The proof of Proposition starts like this: Let $w$ be a point of $B^\circ$. There is a polydisk $P^n(w, \epsilon) \subset B^\circ$ and a point $v \in P^n(w,\epsilon) \cap (\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\})^n$. Then, $T_w \subset B^\circ$, and if $w \in (\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\})^n$, then also $P_w \subset B^\circ$.
I try to understand why $T_w \subset B^\circ$ and why $P_w \subset B^\circ$. My approach is by saying that there exists $w_0 \in (P_v \setminus P_w) \cap (P^n(w,\epsilon) \cap (\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\})^n$. Then, we have that $S(z)$ converges at $w_0 \in T_{w_0}$ which is the distinguished boundary of $P_{w_0}$. Because $T_w \Subset P_{w_0}$ we have that $S(z)$ converges compactly on $P_{w_0}$ (from corollary), which implies that $S(w)$ converges on $T_w$, so $T_w \subset B^\circ$. Also, if $w \in (\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\})^n$, we have that $\overline{P_w} \Subset P_{w_0}$ which implies from the corollary that $\overline{P_w} \subset B^\circ$. Is my approach good or not? Thanks for helping!
